"end of file unexpected" error on my sh script, how can I fix this?
I keep getting the error, what's wrong with my sh script?? I'm very new to this and I don't fully understand what I'm doing but this should work right?
v=0
while [1 == 1]
do
        echo $v
        v=`expr $v + 1`
done


I've tried changing the indents and still get the same error.

You've got several issues here that http://shellcheck.net will identify. (Put spaces around [ and ], don't use expr or backticks in modern code, always quote expansions, use = not ==)

That said, the immediate problem is almost certainly that your file is saved as a DOS text file instead of a UNIX one. DOS files have a carriage return before each newline (and no newline at all at the end of the file), so then looks like $'then\r' and done  looks like $'done\r' so they aren't recognized as syntax.

Please read  the sections Before asking about problematic code, ... AND ... How to turn a bad script into a good question (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash). Good luck!

(the immediate reason the carriage returns cause the specific symptom you're here with is that you have a while, but the shell doesn't recognize your do or done, and it hits the end of the file while looking for them)
